# php simplexml_load_file

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm new to PHP and this may be a stupid question to ask, so don't vote me down just because I don't understand something...

```
php -r "print_r(simplexml_load_file('http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/31139114.rss'));"
```

let's take this for an example, by running this command i get (on screen) XML output.

my question is it possible to save this data instead of just screen but in a file and then read that file and have exact same as if you've have made that simplexml_load_file()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can download the data, using something like [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) ; it'll get you the whole XML in a single PHP string.

For instance :

```
$xml = file_get_contents('http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/31139114.rss');
```

`$xml` now contains the XML string.

Then, you can write that string to a file, using [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/file_put_contents).

For instance :

```
file_put_contents('/home/squale/developpement/tests/temp/test.xml', $xml);
```

And, to check the file, from the command-line :

```
$ cat test.xml                                                                                                                                                                                                   
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>                                                                                                                                                                           
<rss xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0">                                                                                                                                                     
  <channel>                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    <title>Twitter / eBayDailyDeals</title>                                                                                                                                                                      
    <link>http://twitter.com/eBayDailyDeals</link>                                                                                                                                                               
    <atom:link type="application/rss+xml" href="http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/31139114.rss" rel="self"/>                                                                                             
    <description>Twitter updates from eBay Daily Deals / eBayDailyDeals.</description>                                                                                                                           
    <language>en-us</language>                                                                                                                                                                                   
    <ttl>40</ttl>                                                                                                                                                                                                
    <item> 
...
...
```

After that, you can use `simplexml_load_file` to read from that file.

For instance :

```
$data = file_get_contents('/home/squale/developpement/tests/temp/test.xml');
```

And `$data` now contains your XML string ;-)

Considering the XML you get from the remote server is a string, no need to serialize it ; and `file_put_contents` is easier that `fopen`+`fwrite`+`fclose` ;-)

Comment: I'm constantly impressed by the quality and detail of your answers.

Comment: I actually tried and something didn't work for me, although the difference between this example and my actual work is I have to put together a string (XML) and call it against other's site using simplexml_load_file(), so that how I can XML content inside of my $var, but I still don't know how to save it, I've tried file_put_contents() but I couldn't get it to work:(

Comment: To save, you'd do file_put_contents('myfile.xml', $simpleXmlNode->asXML());