# PHP SimpleXML Syntax Error

Tags: php, simplexml

I am working on Twitterbot backend application and I am trying to copy the direct messages in strings that can be saved and then read. If I want to successfully integrate that into my AIML (artifical intelligence markup language) engine.

As I run the file to test it, I get a Parse error:

```
syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE referring to the line "file_put_contents('Program-O/InfoBot2012/test.xml', $direct_messages);"
```

I checked the syntax and there is no apparent error since I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479315/php-simplexml-load-file) thread.

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumer_key,$consumer_secret, $oAuthToken,  $oAuthSecret);

$direct_messages = $connection->get('direct_messages');

$direct_messages = file_get_contents('https://api.twitter.com/1/direct_messages.json')
file_put_contents('Program-O/InfoBot2012/test.xml', $direct_messages);

$direct_messages = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$direct_messages = file_get_contents('https://api.twitter.com/1/direct_messages.json')
                                                                                      ^--
```

You're missing a `;` at the point I've marked.

Comment: file_put_contents requires no "$"

Comment: hello, i added the ; and the $ as suggested but now i get even more errors:

"Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP" and "Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.twitter.com/1/direct_messages.json) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\wamp\www\Program-O\InfoBot2012\directmessage_test.php" referring to the line $direct_messages = file_get_contents('https://api.twitter.com/1/direct_messages.json');

Comment: also these other errors:

"Warning: file_put_contents(Program-O/InfoBot2012/test.xml) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\Program-O\InfoBot2012\directmessage_test.php" referring to the line file_put_contents('Program-O/InfoBot2012/test.xml', $direct_messages);

and "Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "test.xml" in C:\wamp\www\Program-O\InfoBot2012\directmessage_test.php" referring to the line of code $direct_messages = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable php_openssl.dll (dll since you're using windows).

You can do this by opening up php.ini (usually apache/bin/php.ini in your xampp / EasyPHP folder), and remove the ";" before the line "extension=php_openssl.dll" (so you uncomment it), or add 'extension=php_openssl.dll' to the bottom of your file.

This way php_openssl.dll will be loaded, and PHP will know how to handle HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Twitter documentation on [direct_messages api](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/direct_messages), the request `https://api.twitter.com/1/direct_messages.json` will return a JSON response, which you are trying to save and load as XML.

Try `https://api.twitter.com/1/direct_messages.xml` instead.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for ur reply but it doesn't work either by trying with https://api.twitter.com/1/direct_messages.xml...I am getting same errors as previously posted...